# POst array and update mysql table with unique id for each update?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I have this in firebug:

```
s:17:"id=12&id=15&id=16";s:19:"qty=15&qty=5&qty=12";s:43:"note=note+one¬e=note+two¬e=note+three";
```

I have the above as aresult from this:

```
itemid: $('input.id').serialize(),
qty: $('input.qty').serialize(),
note: $('textarea.note').serialize(),  
name: $('input#fname').val(),
phone: $('input#phone').val(),
email:  $('input#email').val()
```

I have this in my php process file:

```
$id             = serialize($_POST['itemid']);
$qty            = serialize($_POST['qty']);
$note           = serialize($_POST['note']);

$ids        = explode(',', $id);    
$qtys       = explode(',', $qty);
$notes      = explode(',', $note);          


$count = count($ids,$qtys,$notes);      

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {               
$query = "UPDATE bookings SET qty='{$qtys[$i]}', note='{$notes[$i]}' WHERE id='{$ids[$i]}'";   
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
```

Really trying to work out how this is done.What has to happen is that an update would occur for each id from the id= array and the values would change in the fields where qty and notes reside.

Is there a really simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance
jonny

Comment: rather then querying each time you can build a string of multiple queries then use [mysqli multi_query()](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @tom thanks for that knowledge. I went to the link and tried to understand the logic. It seems a bit too far out of my reach of understanding. My update query would only be a few lines at most. Is there a simple way to just get the loop goping to do this update?

Comment: it may be a few ids *now* but you don't know how many there can be and as there will be more then one a loop makes sense but rather then executing a query each time you create one query by concatenation like `$qry .= "UPDATE tbl SET fld=val"` and then you use `mysqli::multi_query` pretty much as you would use `mysql_query()` or whatever, the only other thing so far would be using only one variable like `$id = explode(',',serialize($_POST['itemid']));`